# Change in data store lost when restarting application

Tags: javascript, json, extjs, sencha-architect

I created a ExtJS web app.
I have a JSON file with some data in it.
I created a data store and loaded data from JSON.
I also bind the data store with the grid.
The grid shows the data perfectly.

Now I wanted to update some element in the grid, but so that also the data in json gets updated.

I used following code, when someone clicks button:

```
var grid = Ext.getCmp('PersonListing');
var store = Ext.getStore('PersonDataStore');
store.each(function(record,idx){
      val = record.get('Name');
      if(val == "Jon"){
         record.set('Name','David');
      }

      record.commit();
});
console.log(store);
grid.reconfigure(store);
```

Now as soon as this code executes, I can see the name changed in the data grid. But if I refresh the app or restart it, the change is lost.
Data in json file isn't modified.
Why does this happen?
How can I implement this so that change is persisted?

---

Here is code for the store

```
Ext.define('PersonListing.store.PersonDataStore', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.personstore',

    requires: [
        'PersonListing.model.PersonData',
        'Ext.data.proxy.Ajax',
        'Ext.data.reader.Json'
    ],

    constructor: function(cfg) {
        var me = this;
        cfg = cfg || {};
        me.callParent([Ext.apply({
            storeId: 'PersonDataStore',
            autoLoad: true,
            model: 'PersonListing.model.PersonData',
            proxy: {
                type: 'ajax',
                url: 'data/people.json',
                reader: {
                    type: 'json',
                    rootProperty: 'data'
                }
            }
        }, cfg)]);
    }
});
```

Comment: Is your `PersonDataStore` using a proxy? Is the proxy Client or Server based?

Comment: @Alan How can I check that? Please see in the question I added code for the store

Comment: It's using an AJAX proxy, which is a server side proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Your application server needs to implement all the CRUD operators, specifically a `POST` request handler for the `data/people.json` route.

By default, the Ajax Proxy uses the following HTTP methods for CRUD:

`{create: 'POST', read: 'GET', update: 'POST', destroy: 'POST'}`

If you want to override this behavior, set the `actionMethods` property.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0/6.0.1-modern/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax

From the Comments:

To use a local storage proxy set the proxy type to `localstorage`:

```
 constructor: function(cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
        storeId: 'PersonDataStore',
        autoLoad: true,
        model: 'PersonListing.model.PersonData',
        proxy: {
            type: 'localstorage',
        }
    }, cfg)]);
}
```

To initialize the localstorage with your JSON, make an Ajax request at the start, and set the store data to the request.

```
 // Modify to match your JSON format
 Ext.Ajax.request({
      url: 'data/people.json',
      success: function(response){
         var responseObj = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
         var store = Ext.getStore('PersonDataStore');
         Ext.each(responseObj, function(object) {

             // assumes a specific type of response object
             var record =  Ext.create('PersonListing.model.PersonData', object);                        
             store.add(record);                             
         });
         store.sync();
       }
 });
```

Comment: What if I transform it to local store? Will the changes persist? How to transform this to local store? This is a toy app - server logic is not required.

Comment: If you change it to localstore the changes persist, but you will need to load the json data properly.

Comment: Can you please explain to me how to change it to local store, and how to "load the json data propertly" ? I just started with extJS

Comment: I tried creating direct store, and add two methods one for viewing store content, other for editing - this works once - but if I refresh page, the change is lost again. Code is here:  http://codepad.org/DWFukbz8. Can you please help?

Comment: If you want to test with your DirectStore, it also needs proxy, with type `localstorage`. See my edit above specific to your code.

Comment: There is no need for JSON be it simple data - btw. I changed to local store but still same issue, can you please see here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359781/cant-persist-change-in-local-data-store ?